# javascript: localStorage.getItem() returns value on same page, returns null on next page

Tags: javascript

Sorry for this easy question:

I am doing:

```
  localStorage.setItem("eventID", product); // set item to a storage so that we can retrive next page 
  var tests = localStorage.getItem('eventID');

  console.log(tests)
```

I can see in the console that it retrieves the value I stored into it.

Now when I am on the next page:

```
var eventID = localStorage.getItem('eventID');
console.log(eventID)
```

It is returned as null.

How can that be?

This is how I move to the next page:

```
<p class="regText">Please sign in with your account. If you haven't used the app <a href="page_createAcc.html">click here.</a></p>
```

Edit this is the full code:

Page1:

```
getURLArguments();

function getURLArguments(){


  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
  const product = urlParams.get('eventID')

  localStorage.setItem("eventID", product); // set item to a storage so that we can retrive next page 
 
}
```

( I can see it working with console, so the issue is not with the arguments)

Page 2:

```
getEventID();

function getEventID(){
  var eventID = localStorage.getItem('eventID');
  console.log(eventID)

}
```

The page change comes from html (see above).

I tried running this within single folder and on server. Neither works.

Comment: Are both pages running on the same server?

Comment: yeah, both currently are local on my machine inside the same folder.

Comment: You mentioned  folder, why don't you start a local server (from VS Code or Tomcat) and put this files there and try again.?

Comment: must be something you're not showing. setting a *product* into an *event* on a landing/login page then redirect to a registration page, surely there is more to it. please add all relevant code or a link to a repo

Comment: So, it turnes out it works on safari not on firefox...

Comment: @inmon you may add your findings as an answer to this question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that above code is working fine on Safari but not on Firefox. It works on firefox, only when the pages are hosted live. On a local machine, it just didnt work. But the code is correct.